# Printing a variable to 2 decimal places in python IDLE SHELL3.10.7

Tags: python, output, logic, calculation

i have alreaqdy gone through many of the other solutions posted in similar questions but they all lead to a traceback error,so regarding that i'd to know if maybe the problem lies with me or my idle shell version

whenever i run this statement there's always an error...

fee = ((stay-1)*2,"pounds")

print("The charge for this will be %.2f"%fee)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `fee` is not a number but a tuple with (I presume) a number and a string.

Why don't you try something like:

```py
fee = ((stay-1)*2,"pounds")

print("The charge for this will be %.2f" % fee[0])
```

or better yet instead of using [printf-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) :

```py
fee = ((stay-1)*2,"pounds")

print(f"The charge for this will be {fee[0]:.2f}")
```

Comment: thanks for sending out a reply, but it didn't wasn't accepted....it brought an error about "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"  maybe it's just my python version ಥ_ಥ....if you want to go into detail i can send the code

Comment: The code I provided you didn't do any error. If you have an error, it's because you changed the code I provided or you did not give enough context on your problem. Please modify your question by providing a [example]